# How to print setText() on multiple lines of a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

When I print out the raw text from a website,  it will only put one line of text in the `JLabel`, but in the console it will do multiple lines each on their own line.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class closinggui extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
JLabel label;
JButton button;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                closinggui frame = new closinggui();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public void code() throws IOException
{
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.nbcwashington.com/weather/school-closings/").get();
    Elements tags = document.select("p");

    for (Element tag : tags) {
        System.out.println(tag.text());
        label.setText(tag.text());
    }
}
public closinggui() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 449, 524);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    label = new JLabel("");
    label.setBounds(10, 45, 414, 440);
    contentPane.add(label);

    button = new JButton("get closings");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                code();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    button.setBounds(164, 11, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(button);
}
}
```

As a sample it should print out multiple school closings like this:

```
Washington Yu Ying Public Charter School Closed
Whitman-Walker Health Open at 10am
Woodyard Road Nursery Open at 10am
```

But on the label all it shows is 1 line that isn't even a closing it is just in the same HTML tag as the others.  So how do I make indents?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737810/jlabel-show-longer-text-as-multiple-lines/14738193#14738193) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812936/jlabel-new-line-doesnt-work/27813084#27813084)?  You might want to consider if a `JList` or `JTextArea` or `JTable` is more suitable

Comment: *"So how do I make indents?"*  What do 'indents' have to do with 'line breaks'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using html tags:

```
String txt = "<html>";
for (Element tag : tags) {
  txt += tag.text() + "<br/>";
}
txt += "</html>";
label.setText(txt);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><span>this is <br> your text</span></html>");
```

or try

```
setText()
```

with html having 
    `<br>` 
in it.

The `<br>` will break the lines properly.